# Assign record to different type without conversion function in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Brief introduction to the issue I am trying to solve. I have type, which is a subtype of `std_logic_vector`, representing generic frame. I have also few record types, which represent specific types of frame.

```vhdl
  subtype t_frame is std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);

  type t_frame_x is record
    a : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    b : std_logic_vector(19 downto 0);
  end record t_frame_x;

  -- Conversion functions 
  function to_frame_x (
    constant f : t_frame
  ) return t_frame_x;

  function to_frame (
    constant fx : t_frame_x
  ) return t_frame;
```

I would like to be able to assign signals/variables of these types without calling conversion functions. I was thinking about 2 ways to achieve this.

1. Overload assignment operators. However it looks like custom overloading of assignment operators is not possible. I am not 100% as I failed to find this explicitly being said in the standard, but I think so because I have found no examples of such overloading in the IEEE library source codes.
2. Make specific frame record types a subtypes of `t_frame` type. It looks like declaring a record as a subtype is also not possible. I have found no examples in the standard.

Does anyone know if it is possible to assign record to different type without conversion function in VHDL?

Comment: Assignment is not an operator, to answer Q1.. One hack I've seen used in Ada is to overload a convenient unary operator like "+" (since "+ x" is idempotent with "x") with your conversion functions. Should work equally well in VHDL. Not perfect but "keeps the noise down a bit".

Comment: You mean that assignment is not an operator in VHDL, but assignment in other languages usually are operators, aren't they? By the way the trick with unary operators works, at least in GHDL. Thanks.

Comment: The concept of operators comes from mathematics : an operator produces a result without altering any of its arguments. (This allows operators to be treated in special ways, reordering, optimisations, etc without affecting correctness of results). Thus assignment cannot be an operator. But you are correct that some languages are sloppy and get this wrong...

Comment: The two assignments (without conversion) - `t_frame_obj <= t_frame_x_obj.a & t_frame_x_obj.b;` and `t_frame_x_obj <= (a => t_frame_obj(23 downto 20), b => t_frame_object(19 downto 0);` Your question has elements of an XY problem and a Yes/No question.

Comment: @user8352 The shown example is trivial just to show the problem. The records I use have much more fields and using the concatenation method you have presented is tedious and error prone (in the sense of typing mistake).

Comment: Then you're only interesting in discussion and not specifics?

Comment: @AlBundy   You need to show more of your problem.   That said, going from std_logic_vector to a record is non trivial.   OTOH, your record could have unconstrained elements and each separate usage could be a subtype of it.   Unused fields of the record could be 0 length.   You could then make a single pair of functions for converting between the two.   Going further when two subtypes have identical sizes of elements they can be assigned between each other.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question directly:

## Is it possible to assign a record to a different type without conversion function in VHDL?

No, you will need to write a custom conversion function, or split the assignment out manually as per the comment by @user8352. As you say, this looks messy and is error prone, so a custom conversion function (probably inside a package) is the way to go.